# column-wise filtering of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following df.

```
empid  cond1  cond2  cond3 cond4
234     1      0      1     1
7890    2      1      1     0
38476   1      1      0     1
456     0      1      1     0
```

The empid column is of type character and the rest are numeric columns.
I need the list of empids for every cond1, cond2, cond3 , and cond4 that have values greater than 0.
Right now, I'm creating a list of column names from 2:5 , using a for loop to 
iterate over the columns, select and then filter on that particular column.

I feel like it can be done more efficiently using lapply but I am not sure how to include columns to select since I only need empid column in my result.

As output, what would work is may be a new list object, containing values of empid filtered.
So , for example, something like:
new list object,

```
cond1 <- "234","7890","38476"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your goal is a little unclear. Are you saying that you want to produce a list like, "cond1: 234, 7890, 3846; cond2: 7890, 38476, 456; etc"?

Comment: Just edited the post to include my expected output.

Comment: @jdobres exactly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution via base R,

```
aggregate(empid ~ ind, subset(cbind(empid = df$empid, stack(df[-1])), values > 0), list)

#    ind            empid
#1 cond1 234, 7890, 38476
#2 cond2 7890, 38476, 456
#3 cond3   234, 7890, 456
#4 cond4       234, 38476
```

**NOTE:**

If we keep `empid` as a character, it will confuse the `stack` with factor. To avoid that, we can add `as.integer()` in the `subset`, i.e.

```
aggregate(empid ~ ind, subset(cbind(empid = as.integer(df$empid), stack(df[-1])), values > 0), list)
```

Comment: When I try this, I get index values under empid and not the value itself.

Comment: Check the structure (`str()`) of your data frame...maybe it's a factor

Comment: It's showing character in the input df. But in the output, empid is getting creatd as a factor column. Tried including as.character inside cbind, but doesnt seem to work..

Comment: make it an integer and try again. When it's a character, it becomes a factor when we `stack`. That's why

Comment: Worked after converting to empid to numeric. Thank you once again, appreciate the help.

Comment: Just to be a bit more precise, in your output, is empid, just comma separated values or is it c( 234, 7890,38476) ?

Comment: It's a list. Not a string. Try `str()`. If you want a string change the last statement of `aggregate`, from `list`, to `toString`

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate_at(vars(starts_with("cond")), ~ list(empid[. != 0]))

  empid            cond1            cond2          cond3      cond4
1   234 234, 7890, 38476 7890, 38476, 456 234, 7890, 456 234, 38476
2  7890 234, 7890, 38476 7890, 38476, 456 234, 7890, 456 234, 38476
3 38476 234, 7890, 38476 7890, 38476, 456 234, 7890, 456 234, 38476
4   456 234, 7890, 38476 7890, 38476, 456 234, 7890, 456 234, 38476
```

If you are looking for storing it in a long format, with the addition of `tidyr`:

```
df %>%
 pivot_longer(-empid, names_to = "condition") %>%
 group_by(condition) %>%
 summarise(empid = list(empid[value != 0]))

  condition empid    
  <chr>     <list>   
1 cond1     <int [3]>
2 cond2     <int [3]>
3 cond3     <int [3]>
4 cond4     <int [2]>
```